# How to convert return type of 'get_posts()' same as 'wp_get_recent_posts()'?

Tags: posts, get-posts

I have navigation tabs which shows recent posts and some category posts. I manage to successfully implement recent posts by using `$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array( 'numberposts' => 9,));`
and iterating over it by doing:

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]);
}
```

Now for category posts I tried to do `$news_posts = get_posts(array( 'numberposts' => 9, 'category_name' => 'news',));` and since it returns array of objects:

```
    foreach( $news_posts as $temp_news ){
        $news = $temp_news.get_post();
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($news["ID"]);
}
```

But this is not working. I need `$news` in a format such that `$news["ID"]` works because I want to reuse the code. I tried many things and read many sample but nothing works.

Thanks in advance as I am quite novice with PHP and am pretty sure there must an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake here:

```
.....
$news = $temp_news.get_post();
```

remove `.get_post()` from there.

Comment: It is not working. I have already tried that. Does `wp_get_recent_posts()` and `get_posts()` have same return type? I think first one is array of posts while other is array of post objects. Is this creating problem ?